# Easiest way to read the response from WebResponse

Tags: c#

```
private void RespCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest myWebRequest1 = (WebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the Asynchronous response.
        WebResponse webResponse = myWebRequest1.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // TODO:Log the error
    }
}
```

Now having the webResponse object, what is the easiest way to read its contents?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would simply use the async methods on `WebClient` - much easier to work with:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender,args) => {
            if(!args.Cancelled && args.Error == null) {
                string result = args.Result; // do something fun...
            }
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://foo.com/bar"));
```

But to answer the question; assuming it is *text*, something like (noting you may need to specify the encoding):

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // do something fun...
        }
```

Comment: Regarding the second option, the one with GetResponseStream. I think you should dispose the response stream as well, not only the StreamReader, for example, by wrapping your code into a second 'using' structure. In the first 'using' you can get the reference for the stream object, in the second one you can create the StreamReader.

Answer (score 13):

Here is one way to do it if the response is coming in from XML.

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.yoururl.com");
WebResponse response = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.Value.Trim());
    }                       
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The stream must be wrapped with using block.

Comment: @Jayee No, you could also dispose it later on.

Answer (score 9):

```
internal string Get(string uri)
{
    using (WebResponse wr = WebRequest.Create(uri).GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```