# get raw xml response from amazon mws api

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am developing a software solution using Amaon mws api in c#, using the classes from their c# library. I would like to get the xml response info in raw form, not thru their classes which are a little clumsy for my needs. Is there anyway to get out the full xml info from the response object? Please reply

Comment: Refer to the following for reading the response back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533681/easiest-way-to-read-the-response-from-webresponse

Comment: Also have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534080.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've made it easy by serializing everything into objects for you.  You can go through their Sample cs file (MarketplaceWebServiceProductsSample.cs for the [Products API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/products/products/v20111001/cSharp.html/186-5996206-2727469)) and dig out the method you want to call and put it into your own app, and then make the call, get back the serialized objects and then you can do what you want with them, no need to look at raw XML.

However, if you want to, just add the code that is in the `runtime-src` folder of the client library to your project, set a breakpoint and step into the code.  You'll find it in there eventually and then copy out the parts you need.

I've written about a dozen client applications that use the various MWS client libraries and I find them easy to work with.  If you don't like their classes, just write a method that converts theirs to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Im not very sure about C# library.But you can get raw xml response over http connection. You can refer this: 
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IN/feeds/Feeds_GetFeedSubmissionResult.html

All the best :)